# What does App=EntityFramework do in Sql connection string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, connection-string

I have 2 connection strings - 1 local and 1 for my main production server. Entity Framework added App=EntityFramework to my local string when I installed it (4.1) - I'm now on 4.3. What does this do - I can't find any reference to it?

Here's my local connection string:

```
<add name="LocalConnection"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
      connectionString="metadata=
      res://*/;
      provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
      provider connection string='
      Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
      AttachDBFilename=C:\mypath\MyDb.mdf;
      Integrated Security=True;
      User Instance=True;
      MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
      App=EntityFramework'" />
```

Just curious!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just the synonym of the Application Name.

You can see the Connection String properties outlined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that Darren, its a useful resource. I'm a bit of a sql noob, though - so still don't understand why local works and so does remote without this. Is it necessary?

Comment: @dotnetnoob - it isn't a mandatory field.  You could also add an ApplicationName property to the string and call it what you like. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 24):

App and Application Name are simply a way for somebody debugging SQL Server to know which client is connecting to it. If you had a SQL Server that has several apps that used it, it might be hard to know which one was sending which statements. If each app used a different Application Name it would be very clear.

[Check this out](http://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/) for more info.

Comment: Greate answer! Thanks!